# When should we implement `__deepcopy__`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-copy

I would like to know in what situations is interesting/necessary to redefine `__deepcopy__`? Indeed, this method is already implemented in a such a way to perform a deepcopy of an object.

So what is the point of redefining it differently?

Comment: Did not even know about this method. When I define it, it is indeed used by `copy.deepcopy`, but does not seem to be defined by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are cyclic references in the object-graph, things get tricky. The built-in  `__deepcopy__` does in fact handle these, but you may want to customize the approach.

Also, there are objects (the original that you are calling `deepcopy` on or one in its reference graph)  that simply cannot be deep-copied, like file handles, and again, you may want your own approach.